# How to use scylla-driver from Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, scylla

I have several Spark jobs which use Cassandra driver, but there is migration from Cassandra to Scylla. And I want Spark jobs to work with Scylla with shared awareness. As I understand, Spark Cassandra connector uses Cassandra driver which does not support shared awareness in Scylla and works not so fast.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Could you help me please find a way to support Scylla shared awareness in Spark.
For example is it possible to rewrite spark-cassandra-connector project and use inside this dependency instead of a datastax cassandra driver?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.scylladb</groupId>
  <artifactId>scylla-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://java-driver.docs.scylladb.com/stable/

Or do I have to use something like datasource v.2 ?

Comment: You can just replace the cassandra's driver .jar with scylla's shard-aware .jar. They're fully compatible.